# Getting this error when compiling in theos

Tags: jailbreak, theos, cydia

This is the error here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUjl7.jpg

Any ideas? I have no idea what the error means

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your theos tool is either not installed correctly or not in the path it expects it to be or your environment variable that points to it is not set correctly. You are also trying to compile as root which is problematic.  You should be compiling as 'mobile' user and only use root while installing theos.

Type "echo $THEOS" (without quotes) to see if that environment variable is even set. It should point to somewhere like /opt/theos